# Create a polygon on datas

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

Hello I would like to do a script with Python. Actually i would like to open a file which contains datas and then select data creating polygon to remove the datas inside the polygons. I have two codes. The first allows to open a file and displays the data :

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import pylab as plt

import os

from matplotlib.widgets import Button

import Tkinter as tk
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename

abscissa = []
ordinate = []


figure, ax1 = plt.subplots()


class Index(object):
    ind = 0

    def pre(self, event):
        root = tk.Tk()
        root.withdraw()
        file_name = askopenfilename(title = 'Open file', filetypes = [('All','*'),('PGas data', 'pgas')])
        print(file_name)
        array = []
        arrays = []
        indice = []
        with open(file_name, 'r') as ins:
           for line in ins:
               array.append(str(line))

        for i in range(0,len(array)-1):

            if 'abscissa = [' in array[i]:
                indice.append(i)

            elif ']' in array[i]:
                indice.append(i)

            elif 'ordinate = [' in array[i]:
                indice.append(i)
        i1 = indice[0]+1
        while i1 < indice[1]:
            abscissa.append(array[i1])
            i1 = i1 + 1
        i2 = indice[2]+1
        while i2 < indice[3]:
            ordinate.append(array[i2])
            i2 = i2 + 1
        ax1.plot(abscissa, ordinate,'o')
        plt.draw()        

    def nex(self, event):
        a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])
        b = np.array([7,5,6,2,7,1])
        q = ax1.plot(a,b,'.')
        plt.draw()

    def log(self,event):
        ax1.set_xscale('log', basex=10)
        ax1.set_yscale('log', basex=10)
        plt.draw()

    def linear(self,event):
        ax1.set_xscale('linear')
        ax1.set_yscale('linear')
        plt.draw()     


callback = Index()
axpre = plt.axes([0.0, 0.92, 0.08, 0.07])
axnex = plt.axes([0.11, 0.92, 0.08, 0.07])
axlog = plt.axes([0.22, 0.92, 0.08, 0.07])
axlinear = plt.axes([0.33, 0.92, 0.08, 0.07])

bnex = Button(axnex, 'Save')
bnex.on_clicked(callback.nex)

bpre = Button(axpre, 'Open')
bpre.on_clicked(callback.pre)

blog = Button(axlog, 'Log')
blog.on_clicked(callback.log)

blinear = Button(axlinear, 'Linear')
blinear.on_clicked(callback.linear)

plt.show()
```

The second allows to select data like this I click on the left button to do the polygon I clik on the right button to close the polygon and the data inside will remove. But I don't achieve to fusion the two codes. That is to say I want to load data and then create a polygon which allows to remove data inside the polygon. here is my code :

```
import pylab as plt
import numpy as np
from shapely.geometry import Point
from shapely.geometry.polygon import Polygon
#from matplotlib.widgets import Button

a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,50,500])
b = np.array([1,4,5,5,4,5,4,5,9,25,800])
c = plt.plot(a,b, '.')


class Canvas(object):
    def __init__(self,ax):
        self.ax = ax

        # Create handle for a path of connected points
        self.path, = ax.plot([],[],'o-',lw=3)
        self.vert = []


        self.x = [] 
        self.y = []

        self.mouse_button = {1: self._add_point, 2: self._delete_point, 3: self._close_polygon}

    def set_location(self,event):
        if event.inaxes:
            self.x = event.xdata
            self.y = event.ydata

    def _add_point(self):
        self.vert.append((self.x,self.y))

    def _delete_point(self):
        if len(self.vert)>0:
            self.vert.pop()

    def _close_polygon(self):
        global a,b,c
        self.vert.append(self.vert[0])
        myList=[]
        for i in range(0,a.size):
            myList.append(Point(a[i],b[i]))
        polygon = Polygon(self.vert)
        for i1 in range(0,len(a)):
            if polygon.contains(myList[i1]):
                #global a,b
                q = i1 
                a = np.delete(a,q-(len(myList)-len(a)))
                b = np.delete(b,q-(len(myList)-len(b)))

                #q = q-1

        c[0].remove()
        #global c
        c = plt.plot(a,b, 'b.')
        for i2 in range(0,len(self.vert)):
            self.vert.pop()






    def update_path(self,event):

        # If the mouse pointer is not on the canvas, ignore buttons
        if not event.inaxes: return

        # Do whichever action correspond to the mouse button clicked
        self.mouse_button[event.button]()

        x = [self.vert[k][0] for k in range(len(self.vert))]
        y = [self.vert[k][1] for k in range(len(self.vert))]
        self.path.set_data(x,y)
        plt.draw()
if __name__ == '__main__':

    fig = plt.figure(1,(8,8))
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    cnv = Canvas(ax)

    plt.connect('button_press_event',cnv.update_path)
    plt.connect('motion_notify_event',cnv.set_location)

class Index(object):
    ind = 0

    def next(self, event):
        plt.draw()

    def prev(self, event):
        plt.draw()

callback = Index()


plt.show()
```

Thank you very much for your help !!!

Comment: My friend: (1) You're asking us to read much too much code. You need to reduce what you submit to about ten to fifteen lines that exemplify the difficulty you are experiencing. (2) You're asking for help but it's difficult to know precisely what sort of help you want or need. Would you please try to be more specific. You should probably read the help file for stackoverflow.